# CSS Before Selector and Margin issues

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to use the before selector to mimic some behavior of a list item when applied to  elements. I can't use list items so I have to be able to get  styles to work.

Here is a fiddle showing the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/7g6ncg7u/

```
    .container {
    width:300px;
}


.up:before{
    content:'\25B2';
    color:green;
    padding-right:10px;

    margin:1px;

}
.down:before{
    content:'\25BC';
    color:red;
    padding-right:10px;

    margin:1px;

}
```

What I want to have happen is the 2nd line of the 2nd span to align with the text above it, not the start of the line like its presently doing.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `float` like this:

```
.down {
    clear:both;
}
.down:before{
    content:'\25BC';
    float:left; /**ADD THIS**/
    color:red;
    padding-right:10px;
    margin:1px;
}
```

#### <kbd>Check the Snippet Below</kbd>

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
}
.down {
  clear: both;
}
.up:before {
  content: '\25B2';
  color: green;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin: 1px;
}
.down:before {
  content: '\25BC';
  float: left;
  color: red;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="down" style="display: block;">regular bullet point text</span>
  <span class="down" style="display: block;">regular bullet point text but this one is longer and will wrap</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the content of the bullet in a tag, such as a `p` tag. This will separate the bullet from the text and allow you to handle them separately. From there you can change the `span` to `display: table;` and the `p` to `display:table-cell;`.

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7g6ncg7u/5/

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I used, and it seems to work pretty well.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="down" style="display: block;">
        regular bullet point text
    </div>
    <div class="down" style="display: block;">
        regular bullet point text but this one is longer and will wrap
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{

    width:300px;
}

.down 
.up:before{
    content:'\25B2';
    color:green;
    padding-right:10px;
    margin:1px;
}
.down:before{
    content:'\25BC';
    color:red;
    padding-right:10px;
    margin:1px;
}
div {
    padding-left: 1.5em;
    text-indent:-2.0em;
}
```

[image]

Comment: This was close, but the float option works better for the rest of the page layout. Kudos for the text-indent, I didn't even know that was available.